# Objective-C Mapview only works once

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a problem with my mapview. When I go to the view it works but when I go to another view and go back to the mapview it doesn't work anymore. I get the right latitude and longitude when I NSLog() it, so that is not the problem.

Code:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
if(IS_IPHONE5) {
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,300,320,300)];
} else {
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,250,320,250)];
}

mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;

CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = {.latitude =  [testLatitude floatValue], .longitude =  [testLongitude floatValue]};
MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  0.05, .longitudeDelta =  0.05};
MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};

[mapView setRegion:region];
[self.view addSubview:mapView];

CLLocationCoordinate2D annotationCoord;
annotationCoord.latitude = [testLatitude floatValue];
annotationCoord.longitude = [testLongitude floatValue];

MKPointAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotationPoint.coordinate = annotationCoord;
annotationPoint.title = stringTitle;
[mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];

}
```

Comment: Create and add the map view in viewDidLoad.  You can reset the region and add the annotation in viewDidAppear if that's the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

based on what you've shown you keep adding map views (a new one each time the VC appears)
you seem to have forgotten to remove it!?

Answer (score 0):

why are you allocating your mapview in viewdidAppear? it will add you map view multiple times on the screen if it is not removed on viewdidDisAppear

Comment: Thanks for your reaction but where do I have to put it if viewdidAppear isn't good?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are not removing the map view that is already added , what you can do is use 
- (void)viewWillAppear  Method to Remove the map like that

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(map != nil)
   {
    [map removeFromSuperview];
   }
}
```

it will removed the previous map view before adding the new map

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your view:

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
  if(mapView)
    {
     [mapView removeFromSuperview];
    }
 }

}
```

Also to remove all subviews:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
     }
}
```

Comment: try adding this to viewWillAppear

Comment: It says "property subviews not found". Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this it may help

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated];

    if(IS_IPHONE5) {

        if (mapView == nil){

            mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,300,320,300)];
            [mapview setDelegate:self];

        }

    } else {

        if (mapView == nil){

          mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,250,320,250)];
          [mapview setDelegate:self];
        }
    }


//Add ramaining Code

}
```

**viewDidDisappear Code**

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated];
    [mapView removeFromSuperview];
    mapView = nil;

}
```

**ViewDidAppear**: if mapview nil we are creating the mapview otherwise not

**viewDidDisappear**:if we go outside view we are removing the map